# MediaStream on Windows Phone 7

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, mediastreamsource

I'm working on a Windows Phone application that displays an audioStream (as radio) but all I found is how to read a video or audio file using mediaElement.

How can i implement mediaStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find the following link on [Using Smooth Streaming Media Element for Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/giuseppeguerrasio/archive/2010/12/06/using-smooth-streaming-media-element-for-windows-phone-7.aspx) very useful.
Basically, you add a reference to `Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming` and use the control `SmoothStreamingMediaElement` to which you set the `SmoothStreamingSource` property to whatever stream you need to. Cake.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting this answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to play a direct stream source like http://208.53.158.48:8364/ using the smoothstreaming source. But it's not playing this radio station. Could you please guide me how I can play this. Thanks in advance.